# Why is Jsoup.connect().get() not working inside thread in my Android app?

Tags: android, multithreading, jsoup

I am performing a web scraping using Jsoup in my android application upon a button click. I have created my own thread for this purpose. The problem is that the line after Jsoup.connect().get() isn't getting executed. I am unable to figure out the reason behind this. Here is my code:-

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("Check","Inside button click!!");
            //obj=new Helper(et1.getText().toString(),counter);
            counter++;
            //new abc().execute(et1.getText().toString());
            
            Thread t0=new Thread(new Runnable() {
                
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{k=0;
                    Log.e("check","inside thread 0");
                         for(i=1;i<=5;i++){  
                             Log.e("check", "inside loop");
                                String url1="some url";
                                url1=url1+et1.getText().toString();
                                url1=url1+"xyz";
                                Log.e("Check", "Scanned url");
                                org.jsoup.nodes.Document rec=Jsoup.connect(url1).get();
                                //Thread.sleep(5000);
                                Log.e("check", "After jsoup");
                                Elements names=rec.getElementsByTag("img");
                                    for(;k<names.size();k++){
                                    Test.arr[0][k]=names.get(k).attr("alt");
                                    
                                }
                                               
                                   
                               }
                    }catch(Exception E){}
                }
            });
            t0.start();
            
            
            et3.setText(arr[0][3]);
        }
        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the Thread class directly on activities or fragments or on Android at all, use instead a [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or [Hanlder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Sample with AsyncTask:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) 
   {
       YourTask task = new YourTask();
       task.execute();
   }
});
```

Basically your problem is that you are not posting back the data from the thread you've initialised to the main thread.

Comment: Thanx for your reply..but this will limit the level of multithreading to some extent as Android has limited it to 5, though when I am using AsyncTask its working fine.. but I wanted to know what exactly is preventing it from executing here?

Comment: Why you should need more to download some json? The code is executing but you can't get the data because is in another thread.

Comment: Actually this is just a small part of what I have to implement.. If I dont control the degree of multithreading well it will take a lot of time for the complete execution.
Anyways, just one more doubt, suppose I don't want to update anything in UI thread, but instead just store the response into an array which I am currently doing, I should use a handler for that purpose also?